# I need to fix payout issue - example given below (re-edited)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, duplicates

```
Customer Table (usage is kwH)
+----+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+
| ID | Customer | Account_no | Meter_no | Supplier |  Active  | Usage | Repid | 
+----+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Joe      |        123 |      111 | NSTAR    | active   |  20   |  100  |
|  2 | Joe      |        123 |      222 | NSTAR    | active   |  30   |  100  |
|  3 | Joe      |        123 |      150 | NSTAR    | inactive |  60   |  100  |
|  4 | Sam      |        456 |      352 | SEP      | active   |  50   |  100  |
|  5 | Jill     |        789 |      222 | FES      | active   |  40   |  200  |
|  6 | Mike     |        883 |      150 | ABB      | inactive |  40   |  200  |
+----+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+-------+


Payment_Receive (table)
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Account_no | Supplier | Amount_paid | PaymentDate |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|        123 | NSTAR    | 20          | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | 40          | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | -40         | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | 40          | 2011-11-01  |
|        789 | FES      | 50          | 2011-11-01  |
|        883 | ABB      | 30          | 2011-11-01  |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

The two tables are use for rep payout. We do not have control over the payout_table because it comes from outside. This creates certain problems because we can not do one-to-one match between the two tables. Leaving that aside, I would like to have payout calculated for RepID = 100 with certain criteria. This is the output I would like to see for RepId = 100

```
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Account_no | Supplier | Amount_paid |    Usage    | PaymentDate |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|        123 | NSTAR    | 20          |    60*      | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | 40          |    50       | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | -40         |    40       | 2011-11-01  |
|        456 | SEP      | 40          |    40       | 2011-11-01  |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Note here that

- Account_no 123 exists twice in customers table, it must show one time in rep payout
- 3 amounts were paid to account_no 456, all the three must show in the report

Reports are calculated on Monthly basis

---

Script for example (Updated with Usage column)

```
create database testcase
go

use testcase 
go

create table customers (
  id int not null primary key identity,
  customer_name varchar(25),
  account_no int,
  meter_no int,
  supplier varchar(20),
  active varchar(20),
  usage int,
  repid int
)

create table payments_received (
  account_no int,
  supplier varchar(20),
  amount_paid float,
  paymentdate smalldatetime
)

insert into customers values('Joe',123, 111,'NSTAR','active',20,100)
insert into customers values('Joe',123, 222,'NSTAR','active',30, 100)
insert into customers values('Joe',123, 150,'NSTAR','inactive',60,100)

insert into customers values('Sam',456, 352,'SEP','active',40,100)
insert into customers values('Jill',789, 222,'FES','active',40,200)
insert into customers values('Mike',883, 150,'ABB','inactive',40,200)

select * from customers

insert into payments_received values(123,'NSTAR',20,'2011-11-01')
insert into payments_received values(456,'SEP',40,'2011-11-01')
insert into payments_received values(456,'SEP',-40,'2011-11-01')
insert into payments_received values(456,'SEP',40,'2011-11-01')

insert into payments_received values(789,'FES',50,'2011-11-01')
insert into payments_received values(883,'ABB',30,'2011-11-01')

select * from payments_received
```

---

**Updated**: Updated The question and script

- *Usage* been added to Customers table
- *Usage* must appear int the result table

*60 = Notice that there are 2 active records (and one inactive). This could be the sum of the two, the one that is larger. This column is created problem removing duplicates

Comment: +1 for data preparation script

Comment: I've just noticed your data script doesn't match your tables you designed in the question.  My answer uses the table/column names from your data creation scripts.

Comment: You _may_ want to further normalize that `Customer` table.  Which would end up helping you with the data duplication issue...

Comment: I agree with @danihp.  There is a lot of discussion between you, danihp and myself already.  You should move your new question to a new question, and revert this one back to the original form that was accepted.  Continuing to append data to already answered/accepted questions can make some people hesitant to assist you.

Comment: New question posted. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two database brand independent options:

option 1:

```
  Select 
   * 
  from 
      Payment_Receive PR
    inner join 
      (select distinct Account_no, Supplier 
       From Customer where Repid = 100 )  C
    on (PR.Account_no = C.Account_no 
       and PR.Supplier = C.Supplier )
```

option 2:

```
  Select 
   * 
  from 
      Payment_Receive PR
  Where exists
      (select *
       From Customer C
       where 
          Repid = 100 and
          PR.Account_no = C.Account_no and
          PR.Supplier = C.Supplier )
```

**with date range:**

option 1:

```
  Select 
   * 
  from 
      Payment_Receive PR
    inner join 
      (select distinct Account_no, Supplier 
       From Customer where Repid = 100 )  C
    on (PR.Account_no = C.Account_no 
       and PR.Supplier = C.Supplier )
   where
     year(PR.PaymentDate) = 2011 and
     month(PR.PaymentDate) = 11
```

option 2:

```
  Select 
   * 
  from 
      Payment_Receive PR
  Where exists
      (select *
       From Customer C
       where 
          Repid = 100 and
          PR.Account_no = C.Account_no and
          PR.Supplier = C.Supplier )
   and
     year(PR.PaymentDate) = 2011 and
     month(PR.PaymentDate) = 11
```

Comment: I fixed spelling mistakes in the query. The first portion runs and actually gives me the desired result. The second part does not run. Are they suppose to go togather?

Comment: I believe danihp was providing you with two options to answer your question.

Comment: OK with that I fixed the second query as well. That is a neat solution as well. C needs to be added after Customer in second query. Thanks Adam!

Comment: You're welcome. On SO, you can upvote answers you find helpful (accepted or not). This is the best way for someone to see their answer was useful/appreciated/etc.

Comment: Not necessary, only keeping right my answers. Three answers are right now I don't need anything else. See you.

Comment: I need to make one change in this query. Since this report is on monthly basis I would like to add something like this on 4th line first query `where year(paymentdate) = 2011 and month(paymentdate) = 11`, that give the error if I add. Can you rewrite this query

Comment: @AdamWenger, would you like reply this last comment?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I will assume the OP wants to modify my query (as that is the one they accepted) and I will look and add this to my answer.

Comment: I think I may go with @danihp query as it is easier for me to understand. But I will say wait, I need to change the test case a little.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter, at this point, then, please, check my answer as accepted.

Comment: Got around to looking and the performance of these 3 options since we had the test data, and your option 2 was notably more efficient (running sql-server-2008-R2 with tiny dataset) +1 for efficiency

Comment: I redited the question to add one more column. My actual query is more complex. Need a solution for that. I +1 both the answers.

Comment: No body will pay attention to new requeriments (only @adamwenger and I), this is an old question. I think the right way to make major changes is to open a new question.

Comment: What means 60, 50, 40, 40? From where come this numbers? Please, can you explain 'usage' number by number?

Comment: Lets say usage is electricity usage in KWH. I noted 60* that means this value can be other than 60 in the final report but 60 would be ideal. This is basically the estimated usage by a customer(never used in calculation) but is included in report for reference only. Example: If a customer has two account with same Account, No and Supplier (but different meter no), this record shows up twice because usually the two records has different usage and that makes the two record distinct. So distinct does not work to remove this particular duplicate.

Comment: When it is listed twice that means the rep get paid twice for the same account where he should be paid only once because commission is based on Account_No.

Comment: I don't nothing understand. Please, explain numbers one by one. Sample: 60* because ..., 50 because, ... 40 because. ....

Answer (score 2):

I used a CTE to limit your `Customer` table, as well as added support for a specific `YEAR` and `MONTH` based on your question in a comment.

```
WITH customersCte AS
(
   SELECT id, customer_name, account_no, meter_no, supplier, active, repid
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_no ORDER BY account_no ASC) AS rowNumber
   FROM customers
)
SELECT  pr.Account_no, pr.Supplier, pr.Amount_paid, pr.PaymentDate
FROM payments_received AS pr
INNER JOIN customersCte AS c ON pr.account_no = c.account_no
WHERE c.repid = 100
   AND c.rowNumber = 1
   AND YEAR(pr.PaymentDate) = 2011
   AND MONTH(pr.PaymentDate) = 11
```

Comment: This give exact result what I want. In my original case, I have used CROSS APPLY which gives correct result except that account no 123 exists twice in the report. Can we use CROSS APPLY in this case anyways? Just curious.

Comment: I do not want to say you could not use `CROSS APPLY` but off the top of my head, I do not know how I would have made this query using one.

Comment: @danihp It happens, and thank you.  I am pretty sure your `option 2` query is the most efficient answer to his question that's been posted thus far.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out first. I have update the query. Added the Usage column. This is what causes the output query more complicated

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter since the original question you posted here has been answered and accepted, you will get better response from others if you remove the `Usage` edit you made here, and turn that into a new question.  People do not always look at answered questions.

Comment: BTW, dont want to create clutter. But I posted my last question for this puprose, didn't work out, so posted this one. Would be reluctant to post another. But will leave it open and if no one can get to it, of course I will select one of the answer as accepted. I think it shouldn't be a big deal. You know the queries are good and I have voted them up.